# Graphs of the hours of daylight in certain latitudes

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, mathematical-astronomy

### Problem

### [image: problem]

---

### Attempt

We are given that Graph A is North.

Since South is more "dark" when North more "light" I picked the graph that is mirrored horizontally: Graph D.

For East and West I can only guess.

---

> ### Request
>
> - Clarify my logic for Graph D corresponding to South.
> - Explain what Graphs B and C correspond to.

---

### Disclaimers

- This may need problem may require some astrophysics trivia, but this problem was found in "Trigonometry" by I. M. Gelfand, a *(surprise!)* trigonometry textbook.
- I understand that it is preferred that I type the problem out rather than take a picture of the page, however I was not willing to spend time recreating the graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*OK, I think I got it...*

---

### Prerequisites

- I will be calling the graphs by letters A-D. (i.e. A corresponds to Graph A).
- I will be calling the cardinal directions N, E, S, W. (i.e. N corresponds to north).

---

### Solution

A is given to be N.

D is A flipped horizontally. It is fairly obvious that D is S.

*The rest of the solution is where I was stumbling. However, the title actually may have given me a hint. I had assumed that B and C must be in E and W, but I wasn't sure which one corresponded to which. Note that the title says "latitude". This hinted me that the only 2 hemispheres we could possible be talking about is N and S.*

B and C are both A stretched vertically. They ought still be N. We can be a bit more specific, though. It's more-less common knowledge that the amount of daylight in the poles oscillates much more extremely (i.e. larger amplitude). So we can say that C is more N than A and B is more S (but still N) than A.

---

### Answer

- A is N
- B is N (least N of A, B, C)
- C is N (most N of A, B, C)
- D is S

Answer (score 1):

From geography, we know that

Variation in daylight time:

- at equator, and latitudes near equator, is minimum. The daytime is approximately constant throughout the year. So most likely, none of the graphs correspond to this.
- is maximum near poles, so most likely, **plot C** corresponds to a place near arctic circle (not near antarctic circle, since graph **C** is similar to graph **A**, which is lying in north hemisphere.)
- is very less in the latitudes lying between Tropic of Cancer and Tropic of Capricorn. So, it is likely that **plot B** is of a latitude near to Tropic of Cancer (not tropic of Capricorn, by the same argument as the last point.)
- in **plot A** is greater than in plot **B**, but less than that in **C**. So i think this plot is of a latitude between Tropic of Cancer and Arctic Circle. Also, as you figured out, **plot D** corresponds to a region as much south of equator as region **A** is north of it. So, **plot D** should correspond to a region between Tropic of Capricorn and Antarctic Circle.

Read more about Daylight Variation here: [Daytime - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime)